# Is there anyway I can add new property to seal object?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway I can add new property to `JavaScript` `seal` `object`

```js
var obj = {"FirstName":"Tom","LastName":"Gorsuch"};
Object.seal(obj);
obj.MiddleName = "Crouis"; // new property is not added
console.log(obj);
```

**Actual Problem**

I am working in a frame work, frame has its own implementation of browser API method, but there are some methods that are not implemented yet , unfortunately I need those methods and I am getting error

> function not defined

so thought of writing polyfill, Then I came to know they have also `seal` the object

Comment: What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Depending on your real problem you could for example clone the object.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my question

Comment: @DenysSéguret I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

No, that is exactly what [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) prevents.

> there are some methods that I need to polyfill, but the framework also sealed the object

You can clone the object using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and extend that, or implement an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)/[facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) object that has all the methods you need and calls into the framework.